# What kind of diagram is on the Google Calendar API website?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, diagram, dataflow-diagram

The Google Calendar API documentation has the below diagram.
What kind of diagram is this and how do I interpret the different arrows.

[image: Google Calendar API diagram]

Comment: its a flow diagram, it shows you how the different objects in the api are connected  I am not exactly sure this is a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an Entity-Relationship diagram.
Have a look at the Crow's Foot section at:
[Wikipedia- ER model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)